# Custom set "current-menu-item" class for specific pages in WP

Tags: wordpress, navigation, navbar

I'm creating a custom WP theme and I'm using the Wordpress navigation bar. When switching between different pages, WP adds a "current-menu-item" class to link in navigation bar which corresponds to the current page.

However, if that page/post is not present in the nav bar, it doesn't add the "current-menu-item" to any of the nav bar items.

My problem is, when a user visits the page "BLOG" (which is actually a category page) and clicks on a certain post which opens the single.php template, I want the nav bar item "BLOG" to be underlined as it would if the visitor was visiting a blog page.

Sometimes I will want another nav bar item to be underlined when landing on SINGLE, depending on where the user came from (I also have homepage posts, then I'd like HOME to be underlined)

How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a filter and check what page you are currently on using conditional statements and add classes before the menu gets displayed:

```
function add_custom_classes($classes, $item){
    if(is_single() && $item->title == 'BLOG'){
         $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'add_custom_classes' , 10 , 2);
```

Comment: Works very well for all single posts, but I would like some single posts to be under "Home" and others under "Blog", depending on what the parent category of that post is.

Comment: Then you will need to use the `get_the_category()` function with the $item->ID variable

Comment: I tried if(is_single() && get_the_category($item->ID) == 14) -> 14 being the category ID of blog but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: That's because `get_the_category()` doesn't return a value, it returns an array. WordPress has codex for it's functions, it's very useful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category. You would need to write $category = get_the_category($item->ID); then use $category->term_id == 14

Comment: OK, wrote $category = get_the_category($item->ID); if(is_single() &&  $category->term_id == 14) but still no effect. Echoing $item->ID gives me a total of 13 digits

Comment: **NOTE**: The `$item` is not the current page, but rather the current menu item; so `$item->ID` does not give you the page/post's ID.